# Runtime exception for a program to find occurrence of a word

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

In this program, I tried to find the occurrence of the word 'how' in the text 'how are you' which is hardcoded in the beginning. But for some reasons when I ran the program it doesn't stop and prints nothing. So I was just wondering can anyone tell me where I got wrong? Thanks in advance

```
text: .ascii "how are you"
word: .ascii "how"
    .text
    .globl main
main:
Search:#search the occurrence of th word 
        li $s0, 0               # pointer for the text
        li $s1, 0               # pointer for the word 
        li $s7, 0               # counter for occrence

compare:lb $t0, text($s0)        
        addi $s0, $s0, 1
        lb $t1, word($s1)
        addi $s1, $s1, 1
        bne $t0, $t1, next_word # compare next word 
        beq $t6, $s1, bingo     # t6 is the length of the keyword
        j compare               # keep comparing 
bingo:    
        addi $s7, $s7, 1        # occrence + 1    
next_word:     
        li $s1, 0               # refresh the keyword    
loop:   lb $t0, text($s0)    
        addi $s0, $s0, 1    
        bne $t0, 32, loop    
        beq $t7, $s0, print_result     # we have searched the all text 
        j compare 

print_result: 
        la $a0, ($s7)
        li $v0, 1
        syscall

        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Answer (score -1):

The program execution will result in an infinity loop between

```
loop:   lb $t0, text($s0)    
        addi $s0, $s0, 1    
        bne $t0, 32, loop
```

since $t0 stays 0 after jumping back to 'compare' the first time. Use the step-by-step-debugger that is included in Mars. Maybe try to load your values with

```
la $a0, text
lb $t0, 0($a0)
```

instead of

```
lb $t0, text($s0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! but I'm just not sure I understand why $t0 stays o after jumping back? isn't it the next letter in the text string?

Comment: @Heyokkwjy. `lb $t0, text($s0)` is correct; it's a pseudo-instruction if necessary, if `text`'s address doesn't fit in an imm16.  This answer's sequence of 2 instructions is broken (address doesn't depend on the loop counter `$s0`).  But yes, use the MARS debugger to single-step your code and watch register values change.